# Character vectors for subset conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to subset a dataframe with character conditions from a vector!

This works:

```
temp <- USA[USA$RegionName == "Virginia",]
```

Now for a loop I created a column-vector containing all States by name, so I could filter through them:

```
> states

[1] "virginia"       "Alaska"         "Alabama" (...)
```

But if I know try to consign the "RegionName" condition via the column-vector it does not work anymore:

```
temp <- USA[USA$RegionName == states[1],]
```

What I tried so far:

```
paste(states[1])

as.factor(states[1])

as.character(states[1])
```

For recreation of the relevant dataframe:

```
string <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OxCGRT/covid-policy-tracker/master/data/OxCGRT_latest.csv")

USA <- string[string$CountryCode=="USA",]
USA <- USA[USA$Jurisdiction=="STATE_TOTAL",]

states <- unique(USA$RegionName)
```

(In my vector Virginia is just on top for convenience!)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the reproducible example, the first element of 'states' is empty

```
 states[1]
[1] ""
```

We need to remove the blank elements

```
states <- states[nzchar(states)]
```

and then execute the code

```
 dim(USA[USA$RegionName == states[1],])
[1] 569  51
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
The vector elements are indeed ok, I just asked the question very badly; tried to explain the issue in the edit!
Thank you again for your effort; every beginning is difficult and next time I ask my question more precisely!

Comment: @hyperinfer I must admit that your edit is still not clear .  it is not showing where the issue is - ie. related to which part of the code, 2) what the issue is (not working is a very broad definition)

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried akruns option as the classic import function is very very very slow. When using a more modern approach I noticed, that the autoimport makes RegionName a logical and thus every values gets converted to NA. Therefore here is my approach to your problem:

```
# way faster to read in csv data and you need to set all columns to character as autoimport makes RegionName a logical returning all NA
string <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OxCGRT/covid-policy-tracker/master/data/OxCGRT_latest.csv", col_types = cols(.default = "c"))

USA <- string[string$CountryCode=="USA",]
USA <- USA[USA$Jurisdiction=="STATE_TOTAL",]

states <- unique(USA$RegionName)

temp <- USA[USA$RegionName == states[1],]
```

You will have to convert the columns acording to your need or specify exactly when importing which column should be of which data type

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Your tip is worth gold; with the new function the import is much faster! The original problem, I actually got solved, whereby I must admit to myself that my question was poorly posed. I tried to explain the issue in the edit of the original question!

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that this is a poorly asked question. Actually I wanted to subset the dataframe based on two conditions, a date condition and a state condition.

The date condition worked fine. The state condition did not work in combination or alone, so I assumed that the error was here.

In fact, I did a very bizarre transformation of the date from the original source. After I implemented another, much more reliable transformation, the state condition also worked fine, with the code in the question asked.

The error lay as apparently with a badly implemented date transformation! Sorry for the rookie mistake; my next question will be more sophisticated

Comment: I saw your edit, but it is not clear where the issue is `nrow( USA[USA$RegionName == states[1],])#
[1] 573` works fine for me